# ServletContext variable doesn't retain value

Tags: java, servlets

I am coming from a .NET background and trying some basics in Java(Servlets/JSPs). In .NET, we have ViewState, Session, Application variables. From what I read, Application variables have a brother in Java called ServletContext. So I created a simple servlet program

```
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");

    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
    context.setAttribute("savedContextUserName", userName);

    out.println("Hello! " + context.getAttribute("savedContextUserName"));
}
```

I open the browser and pass the following and get the correct ouput, i.e. Hello ! Stuart

```
 http://localhost:8080/ServletProject/SimpleServlet?userName=Stuart
```

I then open another browser instance and pass the following but get Hello ! null

```
 http://localhost:8080/ServletProject/SimpleServlet
```

Shouldn't the context have retained the value Stuart when I opened the new browser instance? .NET's Application variable would have surely retained it. Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is retaining it's value but when you call `http://localhost:8080/ServletProject/SimpleServlet` it will override `ServletContext` attribute to null

```
String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
//now userName is null
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
context.setAttribute("savedContextUserName", userName); //null is now set into the context
```

so you should put there a condition in order to avoid setting the null to the context

```
String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
if(userName != nul && !userName.isEmpty()) {
    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
    context.setAttribute("savedContextUserName", userName);
}
```

Or just print it before setting the value, it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

It sure would if you have code like below(Observe print statement before `setAttribute(...)`):

```
    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
   out.println("Hello! " + context.getAttribute("savedContextUserName"));
    context.setAttribute("savedContextUserName", userName);
```

With your current code, context variable is getting override with `null` first (when you do second call in new browser) and then you are printing.

Comment: `context` is declared just below the line being used.